# Is there any way to create a policy via python SDK or rest API in DataHub?

Tags: datahub

Is there any way to create a policy (either metadata or platform) via python SDK or rest API in [DataHub](https://datahubproject.io/)? It seems that it's only possible to create a policy via DataHub frontend, yet we need to automize this procedure in conjunction with our authentication & authorization system. Thanks!